# How to send email with dropdown as selected using PHPmailer?

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve the dropdown selected and send it to the mail using PHPmailer but I am unable to achieve it it just needs some tweaks !! Also to note that I am using Bulma as a part of my project.

```
 <form action="bug.php" method="POST" class="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="column"></div>
            <div class="column is-5">
              <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Name</label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input
                    class="input"
                    type="text"
                    id="name"
                    name="vname"
                    placeholder="e.g Alex Smith"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
    
              <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Email</label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input
                    class="input"
                    type="email"
                    name="vemail"
                    placeholder="e.g. alexsmith@gmail.com"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
    
              <div class="control">
                <div class="select">
                  <select id="selection" onchange="showradio(this)">
                    <option value="0">Select dropdown</option>
                    <option value="1">Best</option>
                    <option value="2">Bestest</option>
                    <option value="3">Exceptional</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
    
              
    
    <div class="buttons" >
      <button name="btnsubmit" id="btnsend" class="button is-primary is-light">Submit</button>
    </div>
    
    
    
            </div>
            <div class="column"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
```

Now the PHPMailer that I have configured.

```
<?php


$name = $_POST['vname'];
$email = $_POST['vemail'];
$msg = $_POST['vmsg'];





// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'PHPmailer/vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'from24@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'pass';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('messagefrom24@gmail.com', 'Tools');
    $mail->addAddress('messageto@gmail.com', 'To');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->AddAddress("$_POST['emailreceiver']");


    // // Attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'New Bug Submission !';
    $mail->Body   = $msg;

    // $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

?>
```

Simply the code only sends the message, subject, and name but I need to add the text which is selected in the dropdown.

Comment: add name="dropdown" in your select tag then get by $_POST['dropdown'], instead of value="0,1,2 change it to string want to send

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you are missing "name" attribute for select element so, you need to put name="my_dropdown". Also, you will need change value of options from 0,1,2 to the actual text.
If you don't want to change the options value then you can create a simple helper function something like this:

```
function get_dropwown_text() {
 return ["Select dropdown", "Best", "Bestest", "Exceptional"];
}
```

In your view(HTML), you can prepare dropdown using the helper function by:

```
<select id="selection" onchange="showradio(this)">
<?php
foreach(get_dropwown_text() as $k => $v) {
 echo sprintf('<option value="%d">%s</option>', $k, $v);
}             
?>
</select>
```

Now, in your php script you can get the dropdown text by:

```
$dropdown_value = $_POST['my_dropdown']; //will give 1 or 2 or 3
$dropdown_text = get_dropwown_text()[$dropdown_value]; //will give you actual text

//Now you can use the $dropdown_text to send in mail body via PHPmailer
$msg = $dropdown_text;
```

Answer (score 0):

## You have a major vulnerability in your code.

The effect of these lines is to form a **spam gateway**:

```
$msg = $_POST['vmsg'];
$mail->AddAddress("$_POST['emailreceiver']");
$mail->Body   = $msg;
```

*Anyone* can write a script that sends *whatever content they choose* to *whoever they like*, using *your server* to do so. That's a *very* dangerous thing to allow, and such holes are frequently discovered and massively exploited.

To address this you need to change either the use of the email address, or the message content. The former is easier, and the way to do it is to **not** use a submitted address to send to, but a proxy for it.

In your form you might have options like this:

```html
<select name="emailreceiver">
    <option value="sales" selected>Sales</option>
    <option value="support">Technical support</option>
    <option value="accounts">Accounts</option>
</select>
```

Then in your script, map these values to fixed addresses:

```php
$addresses = [
    'sales' => 'sales@example.com',
    'support' => 'support@example.com',
    'accounts' => 'accounts@example.com',
];
//Validate address selection before trying to use it
if (array_key_exists('emailreceiver', $_POST) && array_key_exists($_POST['emailreceiver'], $addresses)) {
    $mail->addAddress($addresses[$_POST['emailreceiver']]);
} else {
    //Fall back to fixed address if selection invalid
    $mail->addAddress('support@example.com');
}
//Validate any email address that was submitted, and use it as a reply-to
if (!$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['vemail'], $_POST['vname'])) {
    die('Invalid email address provided');
}
```

This way there is no external control over who the message is sent to. Take a look at [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) for guidance on how to build a contact form safely.

Quite separately, this is suspicious, suggesting you might not get how composer works:

```
require 'PHPmailer/vendor/autoload.php';
```

The `composer.json` file should be at the top level of your project as a whole, not something specific to PHPMailer. Have a search for tutorials on how to use composer.